# Find original reciepient of email

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, forward

I sent an email to around 30 addresses (seperately).

Some of them replied me back, but the email was forwarded to another address and they replied me from the forwarded address.

Is there anyway I can know what was the email address that I sent to the email before getting a reply for it from the new forwarded address ?

I use outlook 2013.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to tell which of the email addresses originally received the message based on the reply you received.